# How to set a variable in API url according to selection in a Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project, I am getting data from an API and it is a list showing Option 1 and Option 2 which in this case Articles titles. This API depending on the user might show up to 10 Articles so I have made it in the app to show as a list. The user can choose any Artcile to get its details.

Here is the config.api:

```
class Config {
  static const String userArticlesAPI = "api/User/articles/";
  static const String userArticleDetailsAPI = "api/User/article_details/4/"; <-- ID required to be variable
```

I am trying to make the article ID to be a variable on so that the API can directly go to the required API with a specified ID
Here is the homescreen that the users can choose from the list of articles:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Articles_Model>>(
                        future: futureArticles,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<List<Articles_Model>> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Column(
                                children: List.generate(
                                    snapshot.data!.length,
                                    (index) => GFButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                                              context,
                                              '/article_details',
                                              arguments: {
                                                "id": snapshot.data![index].id
                                              },
                                            );
                                          },
                                          text: snapshot.data![index].name,
                                          blockButton: true,
                                        )));
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) ;
                          print(snapshot.error);

                          {
                            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                          }
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        },
                      ),
```

Once the user chooses an article I added an argument to get the ID of the chosen one.

here is the api_service.dart

```
  static Future<List<Article_details_Model>> fetchArticle_details() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userArticlesDetailsAPI);

    final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            'Token XXXXX ',
      },
    );

    final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(responseJson);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Article_detailsModelFromJson(jsonDecode(
          response.body)); 
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load User');
    }
  }
```

My question:

User goes to homescreen finds list of articles. Clicks on article title goes to artcile_details screen after going to "api/User/article_details/{id}/"

How to change the article_details depending on the selected article with the id being the variable that changes the API url location

Answer (score 0):

since there is no `apiURL` in Config class. I assume `userArticlesAPI` is your `apiURL` .

```
 class Config {
  static const String userArticlesAPI = "api/User/articles/";
  static const String userArticleDetailsAPI = "api/User/article_details/"; <-- Removed 4
}
```

What I would do is give a parameter into `fetchArticle_details()` function.
`fetchArticle_details(String id)`  then I would call add it into url.

```
     Future<List> fetchArticle_details(String id) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userArticleDetailsAPI+id);

    final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
        'Token XXXXX ',
      },
    );
//...
```

I hope that's the answer to your question.